# Which factors affect the rate of myonuclear accretion within muscle fibers during strength training?

Tags: strength-training, nutrition, protein, hypertrophy

During muscle hypertrophy induced by strength training, there are at least two separate processes which occur that increase muscle size and strength [[1](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/23517348/)]:

- Increased rates of muscle protein synthesis which creates more contractile proteins
- Myonuclear accretion / addition, i.e. increase in the number of myonuclei within the muscle fibers (donated by myosatellite cells) [[2](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/22621743/)]

It is well established that the following factors affect the rate of muscle protein synthesis  [[3](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3381813/)]:

- Training volume
- Nutrition
- Hormones (testosterone / anabolic steroids)
- Sleep / stress levels

However, it seems that there is less research around which factors affect the rate of myonuclear addition.

For example, we know that during a cutting phase, muscle protein synthesis is reduced even in the presence of sufficient training volume because nutrition is impaired.

Assuming adequate training volume, does the impaired nutrition during a cutting phase also reduce the rate of myonuclear addition? It seems logical, but it is a completely separate process to muscle protein synthesis so it would not be safe to assume this is the case.

Which other factors affect the rate of myonuclear addition?

1: [Mechanisms regulating skeletal muscle growth and atrophy](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/23517348/)

2: [Role of satellite cells in muscle growth and maintenance of muscle mass](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/22621743/)

3: [Muscle protein synthesis in response to nutrition and exercise](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3381813/)

Comment: Simple: - age
- genetics
- metabolism
- diet.